# Inserting matrix in Latexdraw

Tags: pstricks, matrices

I am using LatexDraw for drawing a graph and its corresponding matrix and thereby generating the Pstricks codes.. But I am having problem in inserting the matrix. I have attached here the screen shot.

[image]

I don't know whether a matrix can be inserted that way or not. Please provide me some suggestion.

Comment: It can be but you need single dollar signs. Otherwise it's trying to make a display style equation. But here the context is inline.

Comment: I had tried with single dollar too but its not working.

Comment: @percusse .. oops .. i am sorry. I got my mistake. It works now ! Thanks

Comment: @percusse An answer?

Answer (score 1):

The math equations should here be taken as inline math as the display equations would require a more elaborate set up such as line width and centering and so on. Hence a single dollar pair or `\(`,`\)` is required to render math correctly.